# C language parentheses

Tags: c

I would like to check an array of correct parentheses entry from user like: (()) or [[]], [] and printf an error if ((, {{[, etc
// I'm trying something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char concatenation();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int c, ouinon, i;
    int n;
    char parentheses[n];
    char l;

    printf("- - - - Parenthesage - - - -\n");
    printf("Program élaboré pour faire la concatenation des parentheses.\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){

        printf("tapez ()[]: \n");
        gets(parentheses);
        printf(" %c", parentheses[i]);
        l = parentheses[i];

            if(ouinon == 0){
            printf("Continue 0 arrete 1: \n");
            n++;
        }

    }
    concatenation(l);
}

char concatenation(){
    char a; // prendre la variable 'char l' avec les informations du tableaux
        printf(" %c", a);

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hint: use a stack

Comment: Other Hints - initialize some of your variables; declare function parameters; return function  values ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't assign any value to your variables. When you don't initialize variables, variables take a "random" value. You should initialise your variables.

For exemple:

You don't assign any value to "n", so when you do

```
char parenthese[n];
```

you just create an array of unknow size.

Try to fix it !

**EDIT:**

You seems to don't really know what you are doing, you should check this https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/19980-apprenez-a-programmer-en-c/13300-vous-avez-dit-programmer

This is a really good website to learn code.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the if boolean (yes=0 or no=1) add a value for this variable. Maybe I can initialize with = 0; What about...